# Android Camera Image not uploading in Gallery

Tags: android

Here is my code for the Camera Activity that captures then store the photo.

```
private void cameraIntent(){
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_IMAGE_CODE);
        }
    }
```

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "MyApp" + timeStamp + ".jpeg";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(storageDir.getAbsolutePath()+ "/Pictures/MyApp/");
        dir.mkdir();
        File image_file = new File(dir, imageFileName);
        currentPhotoPath = image_file.getAbsolutePath();
        return image_file;
    }
```

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        Log.d("galleryAddPic", contentUri.toString());
    }
```

And I'm calling these methods by:

```
case R.id.photoSelection_Camera:
                cameraIntent();
                galleryAddPic();
                break;
```

The photo does get saved in the folder when I took a look in the device folder.
**However** it takes really long time for me to see the photo from the gallery.
Anyone know what is the issue here?

Comment: The docs say that this intent is meant to "request the media scanner to scan a file", so maybe it's not expected to be immediate? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE. Anyway, that intent is deprecated in 29, so maybe try using MediaStore instead and see if that works faster.

Comment: `galleryAddPic();` That call is too early as there is no file yet. Call it in onActivityResult() instead.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you it seems like calling galleryAddPic() was called too early. After calling it in onActivityResult(), it works fine.